# jQuery - add class to li, remove from others with default

Tags: jquery

Trying to add a border to the thumbnail video that's playing in the iframe.

```
$('document').ready(function(){

    $("#video-thumbs li").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#video-thumbs li").addClass("current").not(this).removeClass("current");
      });

});
```

```
<iframe width="1020" height="574" id="myvideo" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/Qdse1SEBimw" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
<ul id="video-thumbs">
    <li class="current" style="margin-left: 0;">
    <div id="playbtn" onclick="document.getElementById('myvideo').src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/Qdse1SEBimw'"></div>
    <img src="files/lamb.png" width="326" height="181">
    </li>
    <li>
    <div id="playbtn" onclick="document.getElementById('myvideo').src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/WZknytdWWhI'"></div>
    <img src="files/tuna.png" style="width: 326px">
    </li>
    <li style="margin: 0 0 0 11px">
    <div id="playbtn" onclick="document.getElementById('myvideo').src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/BAembvTjChs'"></div>
    <img src="files/myers.png" width="326" height="181">
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I"m not sure what you're trying to ask exactly because its a bit confusing.  I'm assuming you're having the "current" class on other videos.  I would remove every single current class first then do `$('this').addClass("current");`  I hope this helps, but if you could be a little clearer maybe I could help.

Comment: your code works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/wirey00/pPgmm/

Comment: you say you are trying to add a border to videos in the iframe, but your code just adds and removes a class to elements outside the iframe. What is in the iframe?

Comment: The iframe plays a video large. The thumbnails below swap out the link embedded in the iframe. I want the border to be on whichever thumbnail's video is in the iframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try structuring the HTML differently, and remove those unsigthly onclick functions :

```
<iframe width="1020" height="574" id="myvideo" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/Qdse1SEBimw" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
<ul id="video-thumbs">
    <li style="margin-left: 0;">
        <div class="playbtn" data-url='http://www.youtube.com/embed/Qdse1SEBimw'></div>
        <img src="files/lamb.png" width="326" height="181" class="current">
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="playbtn" data-url='http://www.youtube.com/embed/WZknytdWWhI'></div>
        <img src="files/tuna.png" style="width: 326px">
    </li>
    <li style="margin: 0 0 0 11px">
        <div class="playbtn" data-url='http://www.youtube.com/embed/BAembvTjChs'></div>
        <img src="files/myers.png" width="326" height="181">
    </li>
</ul>​​​​​​​​​
```

Now do some jQuery stuff :

```
$(function(){
    $("#video-thumbs li").on('click', function(){
        $(this).find('img').addClass("current").end()
               .siblings().find('img').removeClass("current");
        $("#myvideo").prop('src', $(this).find('div').data('url'));
    });
});​
```

And it should work fine ? 
Here's a [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/BBMkn/2/)

Answer (score 3):

Switch your logic around:

```
$('document').ready(function(){

    $("#video-thumbs li").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#video-thumbs li").removeClass("current"); // Remove all instances
        $(this).addClass("current"); // Add `.current` to $(this) object only
    });

});
```

Comment: I don't see a flaw in his logic.. Add to all then remove from all but the current clicked?  I think it's probably because it's inside an iframe

Comment: nvm.. it's not inside an iframe

Comment: Or since all the li elements are siblings, `$(this).addClass("current").siblings().removeClass("current");` would be cleaner and target the exact elements, but again, it would be exactly what's in the question, and probably not the problem ?

Comment: Is it possible that it's conflicting with the onclick function that's in the div?

Comment: @adeneo can't believe I missed that lol.. wow been a long day